# How to create React router redirect url

Tags: javascript, redirect, reactjs, react-router

My target is to fire a redirect url event with reactjs. How is that possible? Already tried:

```
  successRedirect(){
      this.transitionTo('/');
  }
```

and

```
successRedirect(){
    this.router.transitionTo('/');          
}
```

Comment: What version of react router are you using? Are you wrapping your component with `withRouter()` ?

Comment: 2.6.1 I use ES6 but I don't know how to proper wrap

Comment: Are you using `browserHistory`/ `hashHistory`? There is no enough information to help you.

Comment: var { Router,
      Route,
      IndexRoute,
      IndexLink,
      Link } = ReactRouter;
var destination = document.querySelector("#container");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use push instead transitionTo

```
this.context.router.push('/contact');

MyClass.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    // app.js
    // a bunch of things here :D
    var routes = require('./routes');
    var RouterContainer = require('./router');

    RouterContainer.set(Router.create({
        routes: routes
    }));
    // someUtils.js
    var router = require('../router');
    router.get().transitionTo('home');
```